# SQL query to get distinct rows from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say we have two tables:

```
Company
+---+-----+
|id | name|
+---+-----+
|1  | bar |
|2  | foo |
+---+-----+

Branch
+----+----+-------+
|cid | id | profit|
+----+----+-------+
|1   | 10 | 100   |
|1   | 11 | 200   |
|2   | 20 | 50    |
+----+----+-------+

--cid in Branch is the foreign key to company id
```

The query is to find out unique companies with at least one branch having profit > 100 say.

One way is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.name 
  FROM Company c, Branch b
  WHERE c.id == b.cid AND b.profit > 100;
```

The particular scenario is that very few companies have branches (basically the entries in Branch table is far fewer than those in Company. Given this information is the above query the best possible? Or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient method may be to use an EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name 
FROM Company c
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM Branch b
 WHERE c.id = b.cid AND b.profit > 100)
```

Comment: I finally decided to go with this given the specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks fine, I would suggest to use ANSI `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.name 
FROM Company c
INNER JOIN Branch b
  ON c.id = b.cid 
WHERE b.profit > 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks right to me, although I might use inner joins vs. cross joins, but identical.  Perhaps using a subquery could make it a little faster -- not sure without trying it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.name 
  FROM Company c JOIN (
    SELECT CID FROM Branch WHERE Profit > 100) t ON c.id = t.id
```

Not sure if that would be any quicker though.